# Will British passport expiring soon be a problem leaving Denmark/entering the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, eu, passport, uk-citizens, denmark

My passport has about 5 months until the expiry date. I want to travel home (to the UK) in February.

I was unaware of the 6 month rule until recently, and to be honest I am confused about where it applies and doesn't apply. I have found conflicting information about it online relating to Denmark. I don't even know if it applies to Denmark (as a non-EU citizen). All I know is that I don't want to plan a trip home and then be not allowed to board a flight.

I have (non permanent) residency in Denmark, but I am a British citizen with a British passport.

Will having about 5 months left on my passport be a problem when going through border control on the Danish side/when trying to leave Denmark? Will they be like "hey, you should have got a new passport before travelling in the EU!" Will it be a problem with either the Danes or the Brits?

My plan would be, if it's not a problem, I will order a new passport once home in the UK.

Thank you for your help! :)
If you have any advice or even just want to point me in the direction of the correct authorities to contact, that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> I was unaware of the 6 month rule until recently, and to be honest I am confused about where it applies and doesn't apply.

The term **6 month rule** is misleading.

The actual rule, for **visitors**, when entering, is:

> Article 6 (1)(a)
> (i) its validity shall extend *at least three months after the **intended date of departure*** from the territory of the Member States. In a justified case of emergency, this obligation may be waived;
> (ii) it shall have been issued **within the previous 10 years**;

As a **resident** of Denmark, the 90 days rule does not apply while in Denmark. While in Denmark, the danish law that applies to validaty of the passport for persons who already have a residence permit would apply (which, on the fly, I could not find. In Germany the law states only that the passport must be valid).

One way or another, leaving Denmark directly to the UK, while the passport is still valid for at least 3 months, is no problem.

Even when travelling through Germany/Belgium, when leaving the Schengen Area with a passport that is still valid for at least 3 months, is no problem.

**Note**:
Until 2018, the United Kingdom issued passports that could be valid longer than 10 years (the remaining time of the previous passport was added).

For the Schengen Area, these passports are now (starting 2021-01-01) only considered valid 10 years after the date of issue, independent of the expiry date stated in the passport.